# How to select column names with spaces using Graph API for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a query like this $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{_config.SubBaseUrl}/items?expand=fields(select=id,Title,MFG_Name,Manufacturer Part Number)"

How can I select the column names with spaces like "Manufacturer Part Number", so I don't get invalid path error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the spaces in the field name by `_x0020_`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{_config.SubBaseUrl}/items?expand=fields(select=id,Title,MFG_Name,Manufacturer_x0020_Part_x0020_Number)
```

Another option is to call query with `expand` without `select` and check the format of the column with spaces. Sometimes Graph API returns column's name without spaces.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{_config.SubBaseUrl}/items?expand=fields
```

So it's possible that for `Manufacturer Part Number` api will return `ManufacturerPartNumber`.